# OpenSource iCarousel in my app

Tags: ios, xcode, coverflow, icarousel

I implementing iCarousel in my app for a CoverFlow. I can't find method for detect, which view is showed right now.

Any body know it? Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), you can use the property `currentItemIndex`:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger currentItemIndex;
```

> The index of the currently centered item in the carousel (read only).

Or the property `currentItemView`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UIView *currentItemView;
```

> The currently centered item view in the carousel. The index of this view matches currentItemIndex.

For example:

```
// Current index
NSInteger currentIndex = myCarousel.currentItemIndex;

// Current view
UIView *currentView = myCarousel.currentItemView;
```

Comment: yeah, but which method? where should i get it?

Comment: i did it in carouselDidScroll thnx

Comment: You should still mark the above answer as the accepted solution since it did actually answer your question. Even if you asked the question wrongly ;)